# C - Function pointer applied to matrix. Segmentation fault error

Tags: c, pointers, matrix, segmentation-fault, function-pointers

I understand *what* a segmentation fault is, but I don't understand why I'm getting it.

So below I've defined a function that takes a char pointer and checks if its a certain character, then replaces it if it's the specified character.

```
int swapPercent(char * loc){
if (strcmp(loc, "%") == 0){
*loc = '#';
}
}
```

Then below is the function pointer function that applies the function to each element in the matrix:

```
int execOnMatrix(char (*fptr)(char)){
int a;
int b;
for (a = 0; a < 10; a = a +1){
  for (b = 0; b < 10; b=b+1){
    (*fptr)(matrixOne[a][b]);
  }
}
}
```

And lastly here is where I call the function execOnMatrix. This is in a separate function where I iterate over the matrix (its a game based on player movement):

```
if (matrixOne[a][b] == '+'){
execOnMatrix(swapPercent());
}
```

EDIT:
The matrix is as follows:

```
char map[10][10];
```

And the 'a' and 'b' in the code above are from a for loop that accesses each element in the matrix.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: and you get segmentation fault where and how you calll it?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: Not enough context, but did you mean `if (*loc == '%')` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
execOnMatrix
```

is defined to take pointer to function taking character:

```
char (*fptr)(char)
```

as argument, but you call it with address of `swapPercent` which is of type

```
int (*f)(char*)
```

Moreover even if the type was correct you call execOnMatrix incorrectly

```
execOnMatrix(swapPercent());
```

calling the function swapPercent. This shoud be

```
execOnMatrix(swapPercent);
```

or equivalently

```
execOnMatrix(&swapPercent);
```

Answer (score 0):

These function types

```
int swapPercent(char * loc );
```

and

```
char (*fptr)(char);
```

are incompatible. This is the reason of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the swapPercent function, not passing it as a parameter. Write:

```
execOnMatrix(&swapPercent);
```

The `&` is optional, but makes it clearer that you intend to pass the address of the function.

Answer (score 0):

The clue to one mistake (at least) is in the way you replace the char.

```
int swapPercent(char * loc){
    if (strcmp(loc, "%") == 0){
        *loc = '#';
    }
}
```

I suggest this should be

```
int swapPercent(char * loc) {
    if (*loc == '%') {
        *loc = '#';
    }
}
```

But, the function still lacks a return value.